# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop, check method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to simple search bar that on input returns the result according to the input keyword:

But the code below doesn't seem to work, nothing is happening when I am searching something in the search bar, also the console is throwing this error "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the render method of `Search`."

I am a newbie, don't know much, any help would be appreciated, also the reason I have put item.name and item.headline in separate divs is because I want to show the content in grid format, so also tell me if I am doing that wrong, and what could have been done?

repo link is [here](https://github.com/ashrth/SearchApp)

```
const Search = () => {
  const [ads, setAds] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    getAds()
  }, [])

  const getAds = async () => {
    let result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/ads")
    result = await result.json()
    setAds(result)
  } 

  const InputHandle = async (event) => {
    let key = event.target.value
    if(key){
      let result = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/ads/${key}`)
      result=await result.json()
      setAds(result)
    
    } else{
      getAds()
    }
    
  }

  return (
    <div className="ads-list">
    
      <input type="" className="searchadsbox" placeholder="Search Ads" onChange={InputHandle} />
      {/* <Search style={{ color: "gray", fontSize: 16 }} /> */}
      {
        ads.map((item)=>
        <ul> 
          
        <div className="adtitle">{item.name}</div> 
        <div> {item.headline} </div>
        
      </ul>
        )
      }
    
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all about the warning you should add a key attribute that should be a unique string to your parent element which is in your map loop like below:

```
items.map((item) => <div key={item.id}>...</div> )
```

Then your DOM is incorrect first that the `ul` element should have directly `li` not `div` element directly! and you should create your map loop for your  `li`s not for whole the ul

```
<ul> 
{
        ads.map((item)=>
          
        <li key={item.id}>
           <div className="adtitle">{item.name}</div> 
        <div> {item.headline} </div>
        </li>
        
        )
      }
      </ul>
```

and change these lines like below:

```
const [result, setResult]= useState([])

const getAds = async () => {
    let result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/ads")
    result = await result.json()
    setAds([...result])
  } 

  const InputHandle = async (event) => {
    if(adds.length){
     const res = adds.filter((item) => // search condition)
     setResult([...res])
}
    
  }
```

and if you wanna show your result in your map loop so you should replace adds.map with result.map

Comment: I made these changes, it worked the warning wasn't there anymore, but my search function is still not working, could you please help me with that, I have been working in this project for the last three days, if you want I can also share the repo link so that you can see the entire code. @n-sh

Comment: @n-sh this code is giving me an error under a curly brace, I don't how to get rid of it

Comment: which curly brace?

Comment: the error is under the second last curly brace

Comment: do you mind taking a quick check into my repo link, it is above in the question part? the code is in component/search

Comment: in your line 27 your code is incorrect const ``` res = ads.filter((item) => ``` ! read the documentation of .filter method here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter . You should write a function in your filter method callback to find your specific items according to your search value

Comment: when I am copy pasting your code then also it is showing that red line under the second last curly brace

Comment: I changed your code in your repo you can see it

Comment: I have not received your pull request yet, sorry for bugging you like this

Comment: Hi, thank you so very much for your efforts, I have added all your changes, I am just facing some error in curly braces

Comment: N.SH can you please answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/74714225/19336351